# Icon list for Polymer

Tags: html, polymer

The polymer starter kit makes references to `<iron-icon>` to implement icons.

For example: `<iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>`

I've checked the `iron-icons` section on the Polymer Catalog website, but the demo which should show all the icons is which is missing.

Is there any other reference of all the icons in the `<iron-icon>` tag?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was wondering the same and asked support in Github through the issues section. They gave me this link: [**Icon list for Polymer**](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-icons?view=demo:demo/index.html)

Here is the reply from one of the organization members:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A searchable list of iron-icons is available here:
[Iron-Icons Search](http://www.twelvetone.tv/iron-icons-search/index.html).

Comment: The question clearly asks for an external resource.  This reference is as good, if not better than the other answers.   I don't understand why you don't delete them as well. "Is there any other reference of all the icons in the <iron-icon> tag"  The answer is YES, which I provided.